# Can't set the minimum date in uidatepicker

Tags: ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I went through many questions and answers here in stack over flow about setting the minimum date in **UIDatepicker**, I have tried most of it but I am still not able to set the minimum date in **UIDatepicker**. My exact requirement is that for people who are aged above 70 should not sign up with my app. This is the code which I have tried but didn't give me the exact result.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *compsII = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:-14];

NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[compsII setYear:1960];

NSDate *minDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:compsII];

datePicker =[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.hidden=NO;
datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
datePicker.minimumDate = minDate;
```

Comment: What is question according to your  description?

Comment: The question is that i want to set minimum date for the UIDatepicker. say I don't want to show years which are below 1960. And the code which I have pasted isn't working. Can anyone please tell me why it is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your minimum date? I mean which date do you want to set the as the minimum date?

Comment: Why did you set maximum date is -14 from current date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your problem

1. You have your min and max dates the wrong way around.
2. You have set the year to -14.

**Update:**

Try this code:

```
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *minDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[minDateComponents setYear:-70];
NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:minDateComponents toDate:todaysDate  options:0];

NSDateComponents *maxDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[maxDateComponents setYear:-14];
NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:maxDateComponents toDate:todaysDate  options:0];
```

Comment: I have set the year to -14 and I am adding that year with the current date to let only the user with age above 14 to sign up. the age range should be from 14-70.

' setminimumdate = [NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:<70 years>] ' this is giving me an error.

Comment: Hi Alex, please check my updated answer. You should be able to plug it into the set min and max methods of the datepicker.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept the answer. I have signed up in stack overflow like 2 weeks before I don't have much point to accept the answer. (I have clicked on accept answer but it says I don't have much points to accept the answer)

Answer (score -2):

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:lblDate.text];

datePicker.minimumDate=date;
```

Comment: Garry please read the question clearly before you post the answer here.Now remove your answer or else update the answer.